# Use EvaluationCompletionAction to notify me only after long evaluation

Tags: front-end, evaluation, options

Is it possible to use the option `EvaluationCompletionAction` to notify me (e.g. with a `Beep[]`) when an evaluation that took longer than, for example, 30s is finished?

One of the default settings for `EvaluationCompletionAction` is `"ShowTiming"` which indicates that the `FrontEnd` is in some way aware of the duration of evaluations.

Ideally, I would want something like this:

```
SetOptions[
  $FrontEnd,
  EvaluationCompletionAction -> Which[duration > 30, Beep[]]
]
```

Is it possible to do this? And could anyone point me in a direction how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible with `EvaluationCompletionAction` but you can wrap input with custom function using `$PreRead` and friends:

```
$Pre = Function[expr, 
   Module[{start, result}, 
     start = AbsoluteTime[];
     result = expr;
     If[AbsoluteTime[] - start > 2, Speak @ "wow, it took at least 2 seconds"];
     result
  ],
  HoldAll
]
```

I'm using `Speak` instead of `Beep` because I can't make the latter work on my machine :P

So now, evaluating

```
Pause[3]
```

should `Print` a message.

Comment: Different approach but it works. Haven't met the `$PreRead` family before...

Comment: @AartGoossens yep, they are quite useful sometimes, you can search around for related answers. I'm glad it helps, good luck. :)

Comment: @AartGoossens Make it `Speak[ ]` something... it is much funnier! You can even randomly choose from a list of jokes...

Comment: @P.Fonseca  :-)) Best idea ever, done :)